Why there is a difference in the volume fraction of a superconductor when you do measurement in Field Cooled (FC) and Zero Field Cooled (ZFC) mode?
Why there is a difference in the volume fraction of a superconductor when you do Field Cooled and Zero field cooled? What does that difference indicate?
